# how get response as list of custom object using volley in android

Tags: android, spring-mvc, android-volley

how to get reponse as a list of custom object using volley in android.i tried some of example but did not get proper answer,can anyone help me please am new to angular

my reponse from sprig rest service

```
 [
    {
    id:01,
    firstName:"naresh"
    lastName:"kumar"
    },
    {
    id:02,
    firstName:"suresh",
    lastName:"kumar"
    }
    ]
```

GsonRequest:

```
package com.example.dh.nareshlearning;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by Darkhorse on 07-03-2017.
 */
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
    public final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Response.Listener<List<T>> listener;
    private final Object dataIn;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url     URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz   Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */

    public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<List<T>> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.dataIn = null;
    }

  /*  public GsonRequest(String url, Object dataIn, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                       Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
        super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
        this.dataIn = dataIn;
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;

    }*/

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
        return gson.toJson(dataIn).getBytes();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        return headers;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String json = new String(
                    response.data,
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(
                    gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                    HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivityextends Activity {

    Button mybtn;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.volley_test);

        mybtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.call_service);

        mybtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

                Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Vehicle>>() {}.getType();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");


                final String requestPayload = new Gson().toJson(new Vehicle(), Vehicle.class);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                GsonRequest<List> myReq = new GsonRequest<List>("http://192.168.10.111:8087/getData",

                     List.class,

                        headers,
                        new Response.Listener<List<Vehicle>>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(List<Vehicle> response) {
                                Gson gson=new Gson();

                                List<Vehicle> lv=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
                              //  gson.fromJson(response,lv.getClass());
                               // ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                                //List<Vehicle> vehicless = mapper.readValue(response, lv.getClass());
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                queue.add(myReq);



            }
        });


    }
}
```

Vehicle class in my spring entity and android

```
Class Vehicle{
int id;
String firstName;
String lastName;
//setters and getters
}
```

Spring rest service

```
@Requestmapping("getData")
public List<Vehicles> getData(){
return repository.findAll(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insted of adding List  i have added JsonArray and i have converted to my my list of object type using Gson.it is working fine

```
 new Response.Listener<JsonArray>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JsonArray json) {
                                    Gson gson=new Gson();
                                    TypeToken<List<Vehicle>> token = new TypeToken<List<Vehicle>>(){};
                                    List<Vehicle> personList = gson.fromJson(json, token.getType());
                                    Log.d("TAG","ReLs:: "+personList.get(0).getVehicleType());
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),personList.get(0).getVehicleType(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
```